# LinqToExcel sometimes results in IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: .net, excel, linq-to-excel

Sometimes when running the code below it results in the error `IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)` from the call to `excelFile.WorksheetNoHeader(0)`.

It doesn't seem to depend on the excel file, one file can be readable one time and the next time not.

Any ideas what could be the cause?

```
    Public Overrides Function GetImportDataAsDataTable() As DataTable
        Dim dataTable = New DataTable
        dataTable.BeginLoadData()
        Try
            Dim excelFile = New ExcelQueryFactory(FileFullPath)
            For Each importDataRow In excelFile.WorksheetNoHeader(0)
                If dataTable.Columns.Count = 0 Then
                    For i = 1 To importDataRow.Count
                        dataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn())
                    Next
                End If
                Dim dataRow = dataTable.NewRow
                dataRow.ItemArray = importDataRow.ToArray
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow)
            Next
        Finally
            dataTable.EndLoadData()
        End Try
        Return dataTable
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an OleDb error.

It looks like a reserved sql word was used. Check out this post for more information: http://forums.asp.net/t/1225443.aspx/1

Comment: Nope, can't be that. I'm just calling the "WorkSheetNoHeaderMethod" and not specifying any columns. And one file sometimes works and sometimes not.

Comment: Carl, did you ever get this sorted out..??